# OpenGL ES 2.0. Sprite Sheet Animation

Tags: textures, sprites, opengl-es2, spritesheet, spritebatch

I've found a bunch of tutorials on how to make this work on Open GL 1 & 1.1 but I can't find it for 2.0.

I would work it out by loading the texture and use a matrix on the vertex shader to move through the sprite sheet.

I'm looking for the most efficient way to do it. I've read that when you do the thing I'm proposing you are constantly changing the VBO's and that that is not good.

**Edit:**
Been doing some research myself. Came upon this two [Updating Texture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9863969/updating-a-texture-in-opengl-with-glteximage2d) and referring to the one before [PBO's](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_pbo.html). I can't use PBO's since i'm using ES version of OpenGL so I suppose the best way is to make FBO's but, what I still don't get, is if I should create a Sprite atlas/batch and make a FBO/loadtexture for each frame of if I should load every frame into the buffer and change just de texture directions.

Comment: Just to be clear, how are you doing your sprites now? Are you drawing a textured quad and changing the texture coordinates on each frame?

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do sprite animation with OpenGL ES shaders is achieved by using uniforms and changing texture coordinates in the vertex shader. To elaborate, suppose you have a 1024x128 sprite sheet with 8 frames.

1. Set up a quad whose vertices (clockwise) are `(-1, -1), (-1, 1), (1, 1), (1, -1)`.
2. Assign texture coordinates to the vertices with `(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0)`, respectively.
3. In the vertex shader, define a uniform `iSpriteFrame` which is set to the frame of the sprite animation you wish to draw (between zero and seven for this example).
4. When you draw the sprite at frame `n`, for each vertex with texture coordinate `tc` and position `p`, calculate the final texture coordinate `ftc` with

   ```
   ftc.x = (iSpriteFrame + tc.x) * 0.125
   ftc.y = tc.y
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I understand the point. So, you think using vertex shader to move around the sprite sheet is the most efficient way to do do it? FBO's is suppose to make a "jump" into OpenGL's pipeline and go directly to the Fragment shaders with the pixels info. wouldn't that be more efficient? Any clues on that?

Comment: The question you're referencing is referring to changing texture data from a running application. That's significantly slower than what's required to do sprite animation. When you do sprite animation, you don't need to change the texture data at all, only which data you're displaying. You shouldn't be worrying about performance anyway. Get something that works and then see if it doesn't meet your needs. With that in mind, I can't think of what techniques would be faster than what I'm suggesting.

Comment: Ok! I'm starting to get the hole idea. So messing up with FBO's switches your texture data on run time… I'll stick to vertex work then. Won't I get problems with too much texture data loaded?

Comment: Yes, this is the classic "compute vs memory" tradeoff that people make all the time. You can stay within your limits most likely by using compressed textures and keeping your sprite sheets manageable.